# Tendermint to run on Android phone

Tags: blockchain, gomobile, tendermint

Is it possible to use gomobile to compile Tendermint and ABCI, then we can run them on Android phones?
I am looking for the tutorial how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

What part would you like to run the phone?

There is the notion of a light client that communicates to other nodes, these nodes can submit and query transactions. The light client does not run the application, allowing for a smaller foot print.

Comment: My intension is trying to run blockchain on IoT. It could be raspberry pi or Android device. Then, they can share information and make decision. So I like to know if we can a way to do this?